# Start web server with express and ejs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to start web server with node.js and Express from Docker container, some people have same problem:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "home" in views directory "./views"
at Function.render (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:580:17)
at ServerResponse.render (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
at /src/app/index.js:18:6
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

To fix it all people add:

```
app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

and render without ejs extension. But, not works for me.

**index.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const PORT = 8080;

var app = express();

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var MyRouter = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

MyRouter.route('/')
    .all(function(req, res){
        res.render('home');
});

app.use(MyRouter);
app.listen(PORT);
```

**Tree:**

```
Dockerfile
src/app/index.js
        node_modules/[...]
        package.json
        package-lock.json
        views/home.ejs
```

In local environnement this works (with or without 'set view engine' etc), but after build docker image and start container the error message appear.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM node:10

WORKDIR /src/app

COPY /src/app/* ./

RUN npm install

CMD ["node","index.js"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have installed ejs as dependency.

Below  code sets the default directory to look up for views in Express.js.

```
app.set('views', './views');
```

Whereas the below code defines which templating engine to use.

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Make sure your views folder resides at the application root level. so home file path should be /app/views/home.ejs

Comment: Thx for response, you say 'sure your views folder resides at the application root level', in local it is but not in container ! The problem : `COPY /src/app/* ./` in Dockerfile, it's not a directory so 'views' folder isn't copied...

With `COPY /src/app ./` works !